# Asterisk random audio within dialplan

Tags: asterisk

I would like to setup a dialplan to play audio at certain durations.
For example..
play an Audio file to say that the call duration is one minute, then play another file stating two minutes, then another saying ten minutes.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use goto and function RAND

```
pro-sip*CLI> core show function RAND 

  -= Info about function 'RAND' =- 

[Synopsis]
Choose a random number in a range.                       

[Description]
Choose a random number between <min> and <max>.  <min> defaults to '0', if
not specified, while <max> defaults  to 'RAND_MAX' (2147483647 on many
systems).
Example:  Set(junky=${RAND(1,8)}); Sets junky to a random number between
1 and 8, inclusive.

[Syntax]
RAND([min][,max])

[Arguments]
Not available

[See Also]
Not available
```

You also can just name files as 1.wav,2.wav etc and use playback(${RAND(1,2)} or you can add that to musiconhold folder and play random MOH

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for as this is totally random.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. You can do any duration based on any distribution using this function.